# Functions: return and or print

Tags: python, function, arguments, return

Suppose I have this function, `funct`, that takes an one argument and returns it.

```
def funct(arg):
    return arg
```

If print `funct`, it should output `None`.

```
print funct(None)
```

If I just run `funct`, it won't print anything.

```
funct(None)
```

Now suppose I want `arg` to be outputted either way, using either of the two above methods, how can I do that? I've already tried this, but it has it's own issues.

```
def funct(arg):
    print arg
    return arg
```

How can I make the function print `arg` either way?

Comment: What do you mean by " it has it's own issues"?

Comment: What are the issues that you're seeing?

Comment: Are you saying you want `arg` to be printed exactly once, whether you call it with `funct(arg)` or `print funct(arg)`?

Comment: @Dalek `print funct(None)` will print `None` two times instead of one.

Comment: @Dano Yes, that is what I want.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want this behavior?

Comment: @SteveJohnson I dont see why you wouldnt just have your function print `None` automatically and avoid the print statement around `funct` altogether

Comment: @SteveJohnson why don't you just write your function like `def funct(arg):    print arg` and when you call it, it just prints the `arg`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only partial solution I can think of is to add a keyword argument that specifies whether or not to `print`:

```
def funct(arg, do_print=True):
    if do_print:
        print(arg)
    return arg
```

Then both of these will print `arg` only once:

```
print funct(None, do_print=False)
funct(None)
```

Otherwise, I don't think this is possible. `funct` has no way of knowing if the caller is going to `print` the value it returns.

Answer (score 0):

You have to realise the distinction between "inside the function" and "outside the function". When you're inside the function you can decide to print the value. But you don't have control there over what happens outside the function.

Likewise, when you're returning the value back to the caller of the function you can also decide there to print it. If you want to print it once, just return the value and print the return value of the function. That way, you can use the function as normal and, if needed, you can print the return value. This will print the value at most once.

So that's how it is.